# JavaScript does not echo values coming from database

Tags: javascript, php

The first thing I get values from database with no problem. Then I can echo the values but after  The values turn in to null. Somehow the values do not pass this point. Here are my codes.

php and mysql part

```
$rows = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kayitlar");
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $rows []= array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'ad' => $row['ad'],
    'saat' => $row['saat'],
  );        

        $i++;


        }
```

No problem till this point. Here is the rest of the code that I am having problem

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "title"    
      },
      animationEnabled: true,
      axisY: {
        title: "Zaman (saat)"
      },
      legend: {
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        horizontalAlign: "center"
      },
      theme: "theme2",
      data: [

      {        
        type: "column",  
        showInLegend: true, 
        legendMarkerColor: "grey",
        legendText: "saat",
        dataPoints: [      

        {y:<?php echo json_encode($row['ad']);  ?>, label: "<?php echo json_encode($row['saat']);  ?> "},


        ]
      }   
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }

  </script>
```

here where I stuck `<?php echo json_encode($row['ad']);  ?>` is getting no value

Comment: Don't use the *deprecated and insecure* `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson What if he's below PHP 5.5 lol

Comment: @OliverNi Then he should _really_ upgrade since those versions haven't been supported for several years. Plus, you can still use MySQLI and PDO on older versions. `mysql_*`-functions are poor and insecure regardless of what PHP version you're using.

Comment: May be "rows" `<?php echo json_encode($rows['ad']);  ?>`

Comment: good guess I am still below 5.5 lol. It will work on local host. That is why I did not pay attention on security part for now.

Comment: @Ivan, did not work

Comment: Can you `var_dump($row);` ?

Comment: `$rows[0]['ad']`

Comment: try this `<?php echo json_encode(array_column($rows,'ad'));  ?>`

Comment: @bantandor See my answer, you need to use `$rows[0]['ad']` because you are changing the 0th element. See this code https://repl.it/KHQG/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $rows array indexed array which contain your keys in every index. So you need to extract your keys value pair from array.

After your while loop completed, add following codes

```
$arr['ad'] = array_column($rows,"ad");
$arr['saat'] = array_column($rows,"saat");
$arr['id'] = array_column($rows,"id");
```

Now use this in your jS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "title"    
      },
      animationEnabled: true,
      axisY: {
        title: "Zaman (saat)"
      },
      legend: {
        verticalAlign: "bottom",
        horizontalAlign: "center"
      },
      theme: "theme2",
      data: [

      {        
        type: "column",  
        showInLegend: true, 
        legendMarkerColor: "grey",
        legendText: "saat",
        dataPoints: [      

        {y:<?php echo json_encode($arr['ad']);  ?>, label: "<?php echo json_encode($arr['saat']);  ?> "},


        ]
      }   
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is `multidimensional array` so  simple use `array_column` to get `specific column` value from each index and apply `json_encode()`

```
<?php echo json_encode(array_column($rows,'ad'));  ?>
<?php echo json_encode(array_column($rows,'saat'));  ?>
```